# Update Statement in Postgres Procedure Doesn't Execute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written a Postgres stored procedure that is used to post-process some input once it has been imported from a CSV. I can properly loop through the table, and a RAISE NOTICE used as a debug statement shows the regular expression worked correctly. However, the UPDATE simply has no effect. Another RAISE NOTICE shows (or claims to show) that the row was updated.

Here's the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ASTRO.PROCESS_YALE_CATALOG()
language plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    YALE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, NAME, RA, DEC, SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL, NOTE_FLAG FROM ASTRO.YALE;
    CURRENT_ID INTEGER;
    P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL VARCHAR(20);
    S_T_REGEXP CONSTANT TEXT = '^([sd|d|sg|g|c])?([O|B|A|F|G|K|M|S|C])?(\d\.?\d?)?(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})?\w*';
    P_ID INTEGER;
    P_NAME VARCHAR(12);
    P_RA VARCHAR(12);
    P_DEC VARCHAR(12);
    P_NOTE_FLAG VARCHAR(1);
    P_MT_WILSON VARCHAR(1);
    P_SPECTRAL_TYPE VARCHAR(1);
    P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB VARCHAR(3);
    P_INTENSITY VARCHAR(4);
    P_UPDATE_COUNT integer;
    REGEXP_RESULT TEXT[];
BEGIN
    OPEN YALE_CURSOR;
    LOOP
        FETCH YALE_CURSOR INTO P_ID, P_NAME, P_RA, P_DEC, P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL, P_NOTE_FLAG;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        IF P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL ~ S_T_REGEX THEN
            -- Trim varchar inputs
            P_NAME = TRIM(P_NAME);
            P_RA = TRIM(P_RA);
            P_DEC = TRIM(P_DEC);
            -- Trim full spectral type in prep for regexp_match
            P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL = TRIM(P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL);
            -- Tear down the full spectral type into components
            REGEXP_RESULT = REGEXP_MATCHES(P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL, S_T_REGEXP);
            -- Assign components to invidual variables
            P_MT_WILSON = REGEXP_RESULT[1];
            P_SPECTRAL_TYPE = REGEXP_RESULT[2];
            P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB = REGEXP_RESULT[3];
            P_INTENSITY = REGEXP_RESULT[4];
            -- For some reason this sometimes comes back as an empty string instead of null
            IF P_INTENSITY = '' THEN
                P_INTENSITY = NULL;
            END IF;
            -- Update row with new values
            UPDATE ASTRO.YALE SET NAME = P_NAME, RA = P_RA, DEC = P_DEC, SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL = P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL, NOTE_FLAG = P_NOTE_FLAG
                WHERE ID = P_ID;
            --GET DIAGNOSTICS P_UPDATE_COUNT = ROW_COUNT;
            --RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATE COUNT: %', P_UPDATE_COUNT;
            -- RAISE NOTICE '% MATCHES REGEX, SPECTRAL_TYPE: %, SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB: %, INTENSITY: %, MT WILSON: %', P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL, P_SPECTRAL_TYPE,
            --     P_SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB, P_INTENSITY, P_MT_WILSON;

        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE YALE_CURSOR;
    COMMIT;
END $$;
```

Since I'm not usually writing database code, this could very well be a stupid mistake on my part. Any help would be appreciated. There are no triggers create with the code.

**UPDATE**

I took the advise from the comments and rewrote this as a trigger, and it worked beautifully. Thank you Frank Heikins for the assistance, if you'd like to post your advice as an answer, I'll accept it.

The actual code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ASTRO.PROCESS_YALE_INPUT() RETURNS TRIGGER
language plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    S_T_REGEXP CONSTANT TEXT = '^([sd|d|sg|g|c])?([O|B|A|F|G|K|M|S|C])?(\d\.?\d?)?(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})?\w*';
    REGEXP_ARRAY TEXT[];
BEGIN
    NEW.NAME = TRIM(NEW.NAME);
    NEW.RA = TRIM(NEW.RA);
    NEW.DEC = TRIM(NEW.DEC);
    NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL = TRIM(NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL);
    IF NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL ~ S_T_REGEXP THEN
        REGEXP_ARRAY = REGEXP_MATCHES(NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_FULL, S_T_REGEXP);
        NEW.MT_WILSON = TRIM(REGEXP_ARRAY[1]);
        NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE = TRIM(REGEXP_ARRAY[2]);
        IF NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE = '' THEN
            NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE = NULL;
        END IF;
        NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB = TRIM(REGEXP_ARRAY[3]);
        IF NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB = '' THEN
            NEW.SPECTRAL_TYPE_SUB = NULL;
        END IF;
        NEW.INTENSITY = TRIM(REGEXP_ARRAY[4]);
        IF NEW.INTENSITY = '' THEN
            NEW.INTENSITY = NULL;
        END IF;
        IF NEW.NOTE_FLAG = '' THEN
            NEW.NOTE_FLAG = NULL;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_YALE_BEFORE_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON ASTRO.YALE
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE ASTRO.PROCESS_YALE_INPUT();
```

Comment: Offtopic, but it could help you to avoid this issue, why do you update the entire table? You could use a BEFORE trigger to get the data correct, before the insert happens. In that case you don't have update anything, and you save database IO for something useful.

Comment: @FrankHeikens mostly because a) I'm not a database developer and didn't know to do that, b) this function will only be run a single time immediately after data import, so it doesn't have to be super efficient. It operates on about 9100 rows of data.

Comment: If it's a one off, why do create a function anyway? Just write a single update and you're done

Comment: @FrankHeikens I wrote the function because I was having issues getting the data just right via update. I honestly spent less time writing this procedure than I did fighting with update statements.